# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3799 for 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_sg

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am developing a neural network model for classifying benign and malware apks.

I have tried using `tf.squeeze()` function but after using it I am unable to use optimizer

```py
def neural_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels= y) )

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
```

The shape of `pred` and `y` must be same however by running the code I am having different shape of `pred` is `(3799,2)` whereas the shape of `y` is `(1,3799)`.

Comment: Is `y` an input `placeholder` or by `y` you refer to the input data?

Comment: y is the label of the input data not a placeholder

Comment: You can't pass input data to a `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` unless you're using eager execution. Are you using eager-execution?

Comment: No, i am not using eager execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My remarks:

- If your labels aren't one-hot encoded you can use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` without converting it to the one-hot encoded representation. Otherwise, `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` accepts only one-hot encoded labels.
- You can't pass `numpy` values as inputs to the loss function (or as inputs to anything except for `feed_dict` in `session.run()`) if you're writing code in a graph mode. Use placeholders instead.

Following is the example to illustrate how to use placeholders and feed numpy arrays of data.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Dummy data with 3 classes for illustration
n_classes =3
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(3799, 2)) # 3799 samples of size (2, ) each
y_train = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_classes, size=(1, 3799))

# Define placeholders here
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(1, None))

# Define your network here
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2, n_classes]), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes, ]), dtype=tf.float32)
logits = tf.matmul(x, w) + b

labels = tf.squeeze(y)
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                                          labels=labels)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

# Training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train})
    print(cost_val) # 1.8630761
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train}) # optimizer step
    cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train})
    print(cost_val) # 1.8619089
```